# Paste only email address without name

Tags: macos, mail.app, copy-paste

In the Mac Mail app, copying an email address of someone in your address book (e.g. from the header of some message) and pasting it elsewhere (e.g. in Text Edit) will result in "first_name last_name <mail address>" being pasted rather than just mail address or at least  "<mail address>".

There used to be a Preference setting for this (see e.g. [this osxdaily.com article](http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/03/stop-pasting-full-names-copy-email-address-mac-os-x-mail/)), but this does not seem to work under Yosemite.

Is there a way to paste only the mail address, also if multiple contacts are copied under Yosemite?

Comment: @grgarside, @TheBro21- I am a bit surprised by your editing of my question. Is there a reason why the second set of quotation marks is now empty rather than showing `mail address` (as before)? The same omission is done in the first quote. As it stands now, the description in my question is simply incorrect.

Comment: That was part of @TheBro21's edit. The removal of code formatting caused the HTML tags to be stripped. I've corrected the mistake and I apologise for missing that in the suggested edit review queue.

Comment: Oh, that was an accident. I also apologize for the mistake I have made.